# How to write a VScode plugin to wrap the terminal input and output?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can the terminal in VScode be extended via plugins?

I want all the terminal input go through the plugin, then send to the server by the plugin.

And all the output of the server go through the plugin, then send to the xterm by the plugin.